# How to find unused libraries in vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm new to VB. I've assigned to the project is to be clean by removing unused references and unused libraries. As I'm new to this project I don't understand how the code written by previous developers. I understand that I can find unused references using Visual studio. For getting Unused libraries I don't see any option in Visual studio. I did research on the internet and I don't find any useful information regarding unused Libraries in the project. Can anyone help on in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from this article [How to: Remove Unused References (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sfxafba%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> To remove unused references
>
> 1. In **Solution Explorer**, double-click the **My Project** node for the project.
>
>    In the **Project Designer**, click the **References** tab.
> 2. Click the **Unused references** button to open the **Unused References** dialog box.
>
>    The project is scanned, and the dialog box is populated with a list
>      of references that are not being referenced in your code.
> 3. In the **Unused References** dialog box, check the references that you wish to remove, and then click **Remove**.
>
>    The selected references will be removed from the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about unused libraries?

Comment: These are "references" to your libraries. If this answer doesn't help you, then we need more information about what you are trying to do.